# Printing struct to a file printing all empty elements of a char array

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program to create a text file, write an unknown amount of structures and other files contents into one main file. When I write a structure to a text file, it writes all the empty elements of a character array, and I want to avoid this. Any idea on how to prevent these elements from being written? I am at a beginning part of the program and am working on building it.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct hdr
{
  int file_size;
  char deleted[1];
  char file_name[256];
};

int main()
{

  //Open the main file, check if the main header exists
  FILE *fp;
  int exists = 0;
  fp = fopen("CS3411TAR.txt","a+b");

  //Check if exists
  char* buf[100];
  while(fscanf(fp," %*s %*s %s ",buf) >0){
    exists = 1;
  }



  if(exists == 0){
    //file header DNE
    struct  hdr create = {atoi("-10"),"0","CS3411 TAR"};
    fwrite( &create, sizeof(struct hdr),1,fp);

  }
  //To-Do  open file arguments names create headers and write

  fclose(fp);



  return 0;
}
```

This is the file output, some elements have been removed as it just continues 200+ odd times

```c
öÿÿÿ0CS3411 TAR^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Im hoping for an output of

```c
-10
0
CS3411 TAR
```

Comment: Read about serialization. You could start simply by writing the length of the string then the bytes of the string and reading in reverse.It's unclear what an array of size 1 buys you over just a regular variable of that type.

Comment: I had it set to just a char, but I had a weird error about casting it. So making into a small array fixed the issue

Comment: When you assign a string to it as you have you're not taking into account the nul terminator and you're writing outside the array. Either assign `'0'`, not the single quotes, or expand it to 2 characters if you're never going to store more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that the `if` clause needs an expression to evaluate.

Your expression `exists = 0` always results in the value of `exists` which is `0`.

Correct the if expression to `!exists` which is a boolean expression to compare `exists` against the value zero.

If `exists` has a value not equal to `0`, you write to the file, otherwise you skip the write statement.

That's what you meant.

Add a `fread` statement instead of `fscanf` to check if the header exists in the file you just opened.

You write binary, so read binary, too.

The real problem appears, when all simple issues are fixed, is: the file opened for appending is positioned at the end of file.

Use `fseek`to position the file pointer everytime you want to read the header or a record from the file.

Here ist my working version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct hdr
{
  int file_size;
  char deleted;
  char file_name[256];
} Header;

const Header defaultHeader = {-10, 0, "CS3411 TAR"};

int main()
{
  //Open the main file, check if the main header exists
  FILE *fp;
  int exists = 0;
  fp = fopen("CS3411TAR.txt", "a+");
  if (!fp)
  {

    perror("Couldn't open file");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  Header header;

  //Check if exists
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  int bytesRead = fread(&header, sizeof(Header), 1, fp);
  printf("bytesRead: %d\n", bytesRead);
  if (bytesRead == 1)
  {
    printf("Header found!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    //file header DNE
    fwrite(&defaultHeader, sizeof(Header), 1, fp);

    printf("Header written.\n");
  }

  //To-Do  open file arguments names create headers and write

  fclose(fp);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Would making the int exists into a boolean affect anything? I am just checking to see if the file has any lines in it and setting an interger to 1. I corrected the statement and ran the code again and it continued to work and prints out only once if ran twice

Comment: In traditional C you just use an `int` and that's okay. If your C compiler understands something like `bool`, feel free to use it with values like `true` and `false`.